# How do I add an older Websphere AppServer "Runtime Environment" to Eclipse (RAD)?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, rad

I'm using the latest version of RAD 9.0. RAD is "Rational Application Developer" --which is basically eclipse with extra functionality (UML Diagrams and whatnot).

**Summary**

How do I add an older "Runtime Environment" to  Websphere AppServer to Eclipse (RAD)?

**Context**

- I need to support Websphere (WAS) 8.0
- RAD 9.0 ships with WAS 8.5
- I have installed WAS 8.0 separately

**Problem**

- Within Eclipse/RAD's "servers" view, I cannot add a WAS 8.0 server.
- If I click on the "download server adapters" link, it does not list Websphere 8.0 Jonas, Jboss, Websphere 8.5, but no older versions of Websphere.
- If I click on "Add..." to add a new "Server runtime environment" then "Search..." to (i.e. to find it on my filesystem), Eclipse/RAD does not recognize my WAS 8.0 directory  as a "runtime" environment.

thanks

Comment: I suspect you don't have the WAS v8 server adapter installed. If you load up InstallationManager and look at the features installed for RAD to see whether it is listed.

Comment: That was it. Put it in 'answer' form and I will accept it.